# Convergence of geometric-like series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

For what values of $p$ does the infinite sum of $p^{\sqrt{n}}$ over $n$ from $1$ to infinity converge?

I thought to consider it in relation to a geometric series, but found that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p^{\sqrt{n}}}{p^n} = \infty$. So now, I am not sure how to think about this. By graphing it for some values of $p$, it seems to converge for $p \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271138/convergence-of-a-series-involving-x-sqrtn

Comment: @Mark Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the solutions
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271138/%E2%80%A6)

None of them makes use of the [generalized Cauchy  condensation test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689794/a-generalization-of-cauchys-condensation-test). In the OP case for $0<p<1$ the sequence $p^{\sqrt{n}}$ is decreasing. Therefore we may apply the condensation test. Choose $n_k=k^2.$ The new series becomes $$\sum (2k+1)p^k $$ which is convergent in an obvious way, say by the ratio test,
or by applying the Abel transformation (summation by parts).

Comment: How can you choose $n_k=k^2$? Which form of the Cauchy condensation test are you using?

Comment: If $a_n\searrow 0$ and $n_k$ satisfies $$d(n_k-n_{k-1})\le n_{k+1}-n_k\le c (n_k-n_{k-1})$$ for some positive constants $c$ and $d$ then $$\sum a_n<\infty \iff \sum (n_{k+1}-n_k)a_{n_k}<\infty$$ The most popularchoice is $n_k=2^k,$ but sometimes other choices are more convenient.

Comment: That's interesting. I know you can replace $2^k$ with $p^k$ for some $p>1$, but never heard about that generalization.

Comment: @Mark The proof goes along the same lines as that for $n_k=2^k.$ Each direction makes use of one of the inequalities. In the case of $n_k=2^k$ the ratio $(n_{k+1}-n_k)/(n_k-n_{k-1})$ is constant and equal $2.$ [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689794/a-generalization-of-cauchys-condensation-test)